# No. of Native(internal) queries executed by hibernate while executing a single query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I tried this but its not working.

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
org.hibernate.Query q1 = (Query) entityManager.createNativeQuery(h); 
System.out.println(((javax.persistence.Query) query).getSingleResult());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Hibernate statistics and use SessionFactory#getStatistics() to retrieve a Statistics and access the metrics related to queries.

See getQueries(), getQueryStatistics(String), QueryStatistics and the other methods.
Refer this [Link](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html)

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactoryForApplication();
Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
stats.getQueryExecutionCount();
```